# setItem in sessionStorage in Chrome not work if I click the URL in suggested url in address bar, but yes if I open DevTool before click on URL

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, storage, session-storage

Description:
I have a react application that launches a setItem function in the sessionStorage on its startup, but this doesn't always work as I expect.

Functioning behaviors:

- if I copy and paste the URL into the address bar this works.
- if I click on the url saved for example in favorites this works
- if I type the whole URL in the address bar this works

Incorrect behaviors:

- only when I type in the address bar and click on the suggestions that google gives me of the app in question, the setItem does not work

Unexpected behavior:

- if I open DevTools first and click on the suggestions given by the address bar the setItem works correctly
- on Firefox everything works as it should
- on Safari everything works as it should

I could not find any information about this, could it be a Chrome problem at this point or can I check something else?

Comment: It's probably due to pre-rendering in Chrome, which works in such scenario, so there's probably some mistake in your code that is triggered in this case, see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/prerender-pages/

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! You're right, was the pre-rendering in Chrome the problem